# onCheckedChanged called automatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, oncheckedchanged, android-switch, switchcompat

I have a switch in a recyclerview and data is displayed in the recyclerview after retrieving data from DB. When the recyclerview is opened I read DB and if a field in DB is "Y" I enable the switch or else I disable the switch.
Now the problem is along with it the onCheckedchanged listener is also called, I want the onCheckedChanged to be called only when user sets the switch manually.

On opening the recyclerview below is executed:

```
holder.enabledisable.setChecked(messengerRecord.get_is_valid().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

ViewHolder class:

```
public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
public SwitchCompat enabledisable;
 public viewHolder(View v) {
            enabledisable = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.enabledisable);
            enabledisable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
...................................
...................................
```

OncheckedChanged method which is called when the recyclerView is just opened:

```
@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.v("ranjith","called oncheckedchanged");
            MessengerRecord rec;
            rec = dbHelper.getRecord(descview.getText().toString());
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
                case R.id.enabledisable:
                    if (isChecked) {
                        rec.set_is_valid("Y");
                        dbHelper.updateRecord(rec);
                     }
}
```

In Layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/enabledisable"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textview_to"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textview_to"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Answer (score 281, accepted):

It's weird all of us have this problem but not official Google answer to this simple problem.

The MOST simple it's to check:

```
buttonView.isPressed()
```

If true, means the user clicked the view.

No global variables are needed.

Comment: This is definitely working. But is there any event if the user slides the switch? In that case, If the used is sliding the switch, this is not working.

Comment: Thanks for this simple yet great solution. This can be used with `RadioButton` as well. For `RadioGroup`, I have written [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266871/selecting-one-radiobutton-value-and-scrolling-back-removing-the-selected-one-in/35237490#35237490).

Comment: Thank's @Surfian for the mention :), i'm glad this works too for RadioButton

Comment: the solution doesn't work if you swipe the Switch very quickly. Stupid Google

Comment: You can handle manually by implementing OnClickListener and checking with isChecked() method of SwitchCompat, didn't require using onCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: yes, this is useless, if you swipe quickly it will return `false`

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
          ... //returns true, if user clicks the switch button        
        }}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the swipe is done very quickly.

Comment: Been an Android developer for over 10 years, never knew of this trick, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I've ended up using this subclass of SwitchCompat to avoid this issue. This way I don't need boilerplate code where I'm using this class.
Whenever you need to change the checked without firing the listener, use `setCheckedSilent` instead of `setChecked`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * Created by emanuel on 30/5/16.
 */
public class Switch extends SwitchCompat {

    private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;

    public Switch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void setCheckedSilent(boolean checked) {
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        super.setChecked(checked);
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

`onRestoreInstanceState` was triggering the listening also, when set in the `onViewCreated` method and you are going back to a previous fragment.
Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 6):

Since `RecyclerView` is recycling views, a previously attached `OnCheckedChangeListener` can be triggered when setting checked value for the `Switch` of the new item.

When binding new data to an item:

```
   switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) // remove any existing listener from recycled view
   switch.isChecked = [true/false] // will no longer trigger any callback to listener
   switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { btnView, isChecked ->
       // do exiting stuff
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. I have multiple `Switch` views in a `Recyclerview` and had exactly that issue. Removing any existing listeners in `onBind()` at first resolved my issues.

Comment: you have to use holder and tag, and set listener only once, this is bad to set listeners again and again on bind

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
 boolean selected = preferences.isChecked();
        yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
            boolean isChecked) {
                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
               preferences.setChecked(isChecked);
                    } else {
                        yourCheckBox.setChecked(selected);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the swipe is done very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin Developers:**

```
    checkboxXYZ.setOnCheckedChangeListener { btnView, isChecked ->
        if (btnView.isPressed) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a global boolean variable and when read a data from DB set it "true" and after check(if) in onCheckChange  set it "false" again. in first of onCheckChange method check if this variable is false execute codes else return(default value of this variable must be false ) ;

```
@Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     if(!isSourceDB){ 

       Log.v("ranjith","called oncheckedchanged");
        MessengerRecord rec;
        rec = dbHelper.getRecord(descview.getText().toString());
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.enabledisable:
                if (isChecked) {
                    rec.set_is_valid("Y");
                    dbHelper.updateRecord(rec);

          }
    }//end if
  isSourceDB = false; }// end oncheckedchange
```

Comment: This seems to be a work around. I was looking for a functionality in android which calls oncheckedchanged only when clicked by user(i.e focus is recevied). But it works. Up vote from me.

Comment: @Ranjith: when Switch clicked first toggle() method is called and in toggle method setchecked() method is called. so you should insert above codes in toggle method not on checkchanged. by the way if you want just write in onCheckChange()  you should write a method that only change the GUI state of switch and called it when read a data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing state in adapter then

```
   holder.rawManageDriverLayoutBinding.rawManageDriverSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

before `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem inside ViewPager screen for fragments. When we switch between fragments, onCheckedChanged Listener is called again and again.

If anyone still looking for this problem, please try it.

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (buttonView.isInTouchMode()) {
              ... //Your code will come here.         
            }
}
```

Comment: it always true for `isInTouchMode` if it's changed automatically or manually, useless

Answer (score -1):

Only solution is to use the method isPressed() in the listener