# Selecting one RadioButton value and scrolling back removing the selected one in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application am displaying 20 multiple choice questions with the help of `RecyclerView`.

If I change the value of first `RadioGroup` and scrolls down, again scrolls up removing the selected value in `RecycelarView` and also i want to use that selected `RadioButton` value further, I was also checked [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28972049/2169192) but i did't understood what he is doing.

Here is my sample code snippet let me know if you need any clarification.

```
    package com.testing.survey;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Student> stList;

    public DataAdapter(List<Student> students) {
        this.stList = students;
    }

    // Create new views
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_row, null);

        // create ViewHolder

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf") @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        viewHolder.tvQuestionNumber.setText(stList.get(position).getQuestionNumber());

        viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(stList.get(position).getQuestion());

        viewHolder.rbAns1.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer1());

        viewHolder.rbAns2.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer2());

        viewHolder.rbAns3.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer3());

        viewHolder.rbAns4.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer4());

        viewHolder.rbAns5.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer4());

        //viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();

        viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());
        viewHolder.rgAnswers.setTag(new Integer(position));


        Log.v("select"+position,stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId()+"");

        viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int clickedPos = ((Integer)group.getTag()).intValue(); 

                //Student contact=(Student)group.getTag();

                //contact.setSelectedRadioButtonId(radioButtonID);
                stList.get(clickedPos).setSelectedRadioButtonId(radioButtonID);


                Log.v("hello"+clickedPos,stList.get(clickedPos).getSelectedRadioButtonId()+"");
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size arraylist
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvQuestionNumber;
        public TextView tvQuestion;

        public RadioGroup rgAnswers;
        public RadioButton rbAns1,rbAns2,rbAns3,rbAns4,rbAns5;

        public Student singlestudent;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            tvQuestionNumber = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionNumber);

            tvQuestion = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
            rgAnswers=(RadioGroup)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rgAnswers);
            rbAns1=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rbAnswer1);
            rbAns2=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rbAnswer2);
            rbAns3=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rbAnswer3);
            rbAns4=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rbAnswer4);
            rbAns5=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rbAnswer5);

        }

    }

    // method to access in activity after updating selection
    public List<Student> getStudentist() {
        return stList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Some thing like that if you select first one radio button it is going to select another radio button automatically while you scrolling down. Right?

Comment: yes exactly, can you help with the solution

Comment: I didn't use RecyclerView but I have implemented with ViewHolders by using setTag and getTag

Comment: i have changed my code can you look once again and suggest me with the solution

Comment: Does it help if you move `viewHolder.rgAnswers.check...` after `viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener...`?

Comment: sorry it was not help full.

Comment: after selecting an answer you also want to unselect it?

Comment: @saikrupa you want to select one value only or mutliple value to be selected?

Comment: Try to remove the radiorgoup and manage the selection from the model class.

Comment: @saikrupa sorry for the very delayed response. I found why it was happening and got a plug-n-play sort of fix for it. You can either scroll down or [click here to go to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266871/selecting-one-radiobutton-value-and-scrolling-back-removing-the-selected-one-in/35237490#35237490).

Comment: @saikrupa I am also getting the same problem with radio buttons while scroliing. If you have got the solution then please help.

Comment: you need to update the status of radio button in your model for your reference follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34451547/2169192

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a sample code that will work as per your req.

First we have to create the xml as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewAppList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then we will create an interface as follows

```
public interface OnOptionSelected {
public void onOptionSelected(int position,int itemSelected);
}
```

Then we will create the model class as follows :

```
public class QuestionModel {

private String question;
private int seleectedAnswerPosition;
private boolean op1Sel,op2Sel,op3Sel; // options 

public boolean isOp1Sel() {
    return op1Sel;
   }

public void setOp1Sel(boolean op1Sel) {
    this.op1Sel = op1Sel;
    if(op1Sel){ // To make sure only one option is selected at a time
        setOp2Sel(false);
        setOp3Sel(false);
    }
   }

    public boolean isOp2Sel() {
      return op2Sel;
   }

   public void setOp2Sel(boolean op2Sel) {
    this.op2Sel = op2Sel;
    if(op2Sel){
        setOp1Sel(false);
        setOp3Sel(false);
     }
      }

 public boolean isOp3Sel() {
    return op3Sel;
     }

 public void setOp3Sel(boolean op3Sel) {
    this.op3Sel = op3Sel;
    if(op3Sel){
        setOp2Sel(false);
        setOp1Sel(false);
     }
    }

    public int getSeleectedAnswerPosition() {
    return seleectedAnswerPosition;
    }

  public void setSeleectedAnswerPosition(int seleectedAnswerPosition) {
    this.seleectedAnswerPosition = seleectedAnswerPosition;
   }

  public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
  }
 public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
  }
     }
```

Then we will create the view for row :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/question"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radoptionOne"
        android:text="May Be"
        android:checked="false"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/radoptionTwo"
        android:text="NO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/radoptionThree"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter class as follows:

```
 public class QuestionAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private List<QuestionModel> questionModels;


public void setOnOptionSelected(OnOptionSelected onOptionSelected) {
    this.onOptionSelected = onOptionSelected;
}

private OnOptionSelected onOptionSelected;


public List<QuestionModel> getQuestionModels() {
    return questionModels;
}

public void setQuestionModels(List<QuestionModel> questionModels) {
    this.questionModels = questionModels;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView question;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton op1, op2, op3;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
        //radioGroup=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radGroup);
        op1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radoptionOne);
        op2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radoptionTwo);
        op3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radoptionThree);
        op1.setOnClickListener(this);
        op2.setOnClickListener(this);
        op3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radoptionOne:
                onOptionSelected.onOptionSelected(getAdapterPosition(), 1);
                break;

            case R.id.radoptionTwo:
                onOptionSelected.onOptionSelected(getAdapterPosition(), 2);
                break;

            case R.id.radoptionThree:
                onOptionSelected.onOptionSelected(getAdapterPosition(), 3);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    // create a normal view
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.question.setText(questionModels.get(position).getQuestion());

    Log.e("POSITION" + position, "1" + questionModels.get(position).isOp1Sel());

    Log.e("POSITION" + position, "2" + questionModels.get(position).isOp2Sel());
    Log.e("POSITION" + position, "3" + questionModels.get(position).isOp3Sel());


    viewHolder.op1.setChecked(questionModels.get(position).isOp1Sel());
    viewHolder.op2.setChecked(questionModels.get(position).isOp2Sel());
    viewHolder.op3.setChecked(questionModels.get(position).isOp3Sel());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (questionModels != null) {
        return questionModels.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Then the Activity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnOptionSelected{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<QuestionModel> questionModels;
private  QuestionAdapter questionAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAppList);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    questionModels=new ArrayList<QuestionModel>();
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        QuestionModel questionModel=new QuestionModel();
        questionModel.setQuestion("Question " + (i + 1));
        questionModels.add(questionModel);
    }
    questionAdapter =new QuestionAdapter();
    questionAdapter.setOnOptionSelected(this);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    questionAdapter.setQuestionModels(questionModels);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onOptionSelected(int position, int itemSelected) {
    questionModels.get(position).setSeleectedAnswerPosition(itemSelected);
    switch (itemSelected){
        case 1:
            questionModels.get(position).setOp1Sel(true);
            break;

        case 2:
            questionModels.get(position).setOp2Sel(true);
            break;
        case 3:
            ((QuestionModel)questionModels.get(position)).setOp3Sel(true);
            break;
    }
    questionAdapter.setQuestionModels(questionModels);
    questionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   // mRecyclerView.setAdapter(questionAdapter);

}
 }
```

I tried the solution with Radiogroup but it was not working properly( sometime it was retaining the old  value). Then I changed the way of the selecting options in my model class.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 7):

This problem occurs because of a bug in either `RecyclerView` or somewhere in the Android SDK. Anyway, I took the advice from another SO question - [onCheckedChanged called automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219410/1276636).

For `RadioGroup`, it will be a little different. There are two ways to go about. I recommend 1st one since it is plug-n-play.

1. set `OnCheckedChangeListener` on `RadioGroup`:

   ```
   mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
           if(checkedId == -1) {
               Log.v("onCheck", "Android bug since RadioButton doesn't get unchecked normally!");
           }
           else {
               Log.v("onCheck", "Valid click. By user");
               mMyListObjectArr[position].setChecked(checkedId);
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. or set `onCheckedChangeListener` on all `RadioButton`s inside the `RadioGroup`:

   ```
   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if(buttonView.isPressed()) {
               Log.v("onCheck", position + ", valid click by user");
               mMyListObjectArr[position].setChecked(buttonView.getId());
           }
           else {
               Log.v("onCheck", "Android bug");
           }
       }
   };
   mRadioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
   mRadioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
   ```

Comment: hmmm what is `mMyListObjectArr[position]` I tried to use my `private List<Exam> mExam;` e.g `mExam[position].setChecked(buttonView.getId()); ` but it says array expected, found List. How can I arrive to it being an array?

Comment: @Woppi just as it says, you're providing a `List` where it is expecting an array.

Comment: @Woppi as you know item from array can be get using `anArray[position]`, while item from `List` can be obtained using `aList.get(position)`. You'd do similar in here. And `mMyListObjectArr` is the list of objects that you're showing in the `RecyclerView`. So basically it is `List<Student> stList` in the OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

Modify your `onBindViewHolder()` to this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        final int pos = position;

        viewHolder.tvQuestionNumber.setText(stList.get(position).getQuestionNumber() + "");

        viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(stList.get(position).getQuestion());

        viewHolder.rbAns1.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer1());

        viewHolder.rbAns2.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer2());

        viewHolder.rbAns3.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer3());

        viewHolder.rbAns4.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer4());

        viewHolder.rbAns5.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer5());

        //viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();

        viewHolder.rgAnswers.setTag(position);


        Log.v("select" + position, stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId() + "");

        viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int clickedPos = (Integer) group.getTag();


               stList.get(clickedPos).setSelectedRadioButtonId(radioButtonID);

               // if you want to get selected button's info such as tag, text... etc.
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(radioButtonID);

                if(radioButton != null) {
                    String customTag = radioButton.getTag().toString();
                    stList.get(clickedPos).setCustomTag(customTag);
                }


                Log.v("hello" + clickedPos, stList.get(clickedPos).getSelectedRadioButtonId() + "");
            }
        });

        viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());

    }
```

It should work. If any issues please let me know.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! This worked for me. You saved the day! :)

Comment: In here, how can I get the tag of specific radio button. I am getting `android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference` when I tried `RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) viewHolder.rgAnswers.findViewById(radioButtonID);` Log.d("TRACE", "radio button id" + radioButton.getText());

Comment: `viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(radioButtonID)` , like this you need to do.

Comment: hmmmm same error. This error does not appear when I get tag or text from viewholder. When I moved the listener to onBindViewHolder to resolve the recycler view checked state issue... it's returning null reference. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/arvi/42d0922bc994e240c6190e30fb1882e3

Comment: Can you once try with `group.findViewById()`?

Comment: Hmmm did that too but same error `RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(radioButtonID); Log.d("TRACE", radioButton.getText().toString());`

Comment: Only when I comment `itemViewHolder.radioGroupPossibleAnswers.check(mExam.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());` it will not produce that error... but then the recyclerview "checked" bug is back.

Comment: But, is that needed to print log message? Without that, isn't it possible?

Comment: hmmm, what I wanted, is when I clicked on the radio button I can get the tag of that button so I can compare if answer is correct. adding the `itemViewHolder.radioGroupPossibleAnswers.check(mExam.get(pos‌​ition).getSelectedRa‌​dioButtonId());` seems to make the getTag, getText point to null reference... hmmm I'm still debugging and tracing what could be the issue... so for that is what I observed

Comment: Will tell tomorrow. Because, I am in office and can't move to this. I also need to debug.

Comment: finally solved it... make sure to check for null and not dynamically set id of button programmatically. Once I did that.... damn it worked! Thanks a lot. I'll edit your answer to add getting of tags.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in this way.....

inside your bean class add one field say

```
String final_answer;
public String getFinalAnswer(){
  return final_answer;
}

public void setFinalAnswer(String final_answer){
  this.final_answer = final_answer;
}
```

in adapter.....

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    final Student student = stList.get(position);

    viewHolder.tvQuestionNumber.setText(student.getQuestionNumber());

    viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(student.getQuestion());

    viewHolder.rbAns1.setText(student.getAnswer1());

    viewHolder.rbAns2.setText(student.getAnswer2());

    viewHolder.rbAns3.setText(student.getAnswer3());

    viewHolder.rbAns4.setText(student.getAnswer4());

    viewHolder.rbAns5.setText(student.getAnswer4());

    viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();

   if(student.getSelectedRadioButtonId()!=null)
     viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(student.getSelectedRadioButtonId());
   else
     viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();

    viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          if(checkedId != -1){
            student.setSelectedRadioButtonId(checkedId);
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)viewHolder.rgAnswers.
                                  findViewById(checkedId);

            student.setFinalAnswer(rb.getText);
            stList.get(position) = student;
          }
        }
    });
}
```

To get selected answers finally...write this code in main activity

```
  public void getSelectedAnswers(){

       for(int i=0;i<slist.length;i++){
          //get selected answer
          Log.i("answer",slist.get(i).getFinalAnswer());
       }
    }
```

Comment: there is a problem in this if i scroll down the 7 the and 8 answers are automatically selecting based on 1 st and 2 nd, how can we fix this. and am also sharing the git link you can check the code there. https://github.com/saikrupa/Survay

Comment: but not every time it's selecting some times only i was changed only 1 line of text from your present code i.e (`stList.get(position).add(student);`) instead of  `stList.get(position) = student;` and i was also added to master class

`public void add(Student student) {
   this.setSelectedRadioButtonId(student.getSelectedRadioButtonId());
  
  
 }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the recycler view is recycling (like the name says) your views.

The system creates a certain amount of ViewHolders to fill your screen after reaching that amount it reuses the already existent ViewHolders.

If you set the button checked in your first listentry and it reuses the ViewHolder for your 7th listentry the button is still checked(because it got set in the ViewHolder).

To fix this problem you need to set the default appearance for your listentries in onBindViewHOlder every time.

Update:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    final Student student = stList.get(position);

    viewHolder.tvQuestionNumber.setText(student.getQuestionNumber());

    viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(student.getQuestion());

    viewHolder.rbAns1.setText(student.getAnswer1());

    viewHolder.rbAns2.setText(student.getAnswer2());

    viewHolder.rbAns3.setText(student.getAnswer3());

    viewHolder.rbAns4.setText(student.getAnswer4());

    viewHolder.rbAns5.setText(student.getAnswer4());

    viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();

    viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(student.getSelectedRadioButtonId());

    viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            student.setSelectedRadioButtonId(checkedId);
            Log.v("hello"+position,checkedId+"");
        }
    });
}
```

I slightly updated your new approach, maybe this helps ?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help, you're setting all the buttons to not checked. What if a user checks one scrolls down and then back up, you would need to reset the original checked state instead of unchecking them all. Furthur, what are you doing with `setTag()` looking at the doc it seems completely unrelated: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

Comment: i was changes my code in the above way please have a look on it am sill getting the same problem

Comment: I updated my anwser once more, if you still have problems it would be nice if you could provide more information  about the problem (e.g. a screenshot).

Comment: upVoted but the answer is not usefull once check the code which is edited

Answer (score 0):

In your model class add

```
private int checkedId = -1;

public int getCheckedId() {
    return checkedId;
}

public void setCheckedId(int checkedId) {
    this.checkedId = checkedId;
}
```

and change onBindViewHolder in adapter like this:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(stList.get(position).getQuestion());

    viewHolder.rbAns1.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer1());
    viewHolder.rbAns2.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer2());
    viewHolder.rbAns3.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer3());
    viewHolder.rbAns4.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer4());
    viewHolder.rbAns5.setText(stList.get(position).getAnswer5());

    viewHolder.radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rgp, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stList.get(position).setCheckedId(rgp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        }
    });

    viewHolder.radGrp.check(stList.get(position).getCheckedId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen your code...

just add single line

`viewHolder.rgAnswers.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);`

in `onBindViewHolder()` method above of this line

`viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());` ...

**if it solved your problem ..let me know ...**
**i will explain you a scenario why its happening ..** **Because i faced** **similer problem and solved using this solution.**

Comment: then how can i store the selected answer.

Comment: I think you are storing a selected answer in `onCheckChangedListner()`

Comment: yes am storing the answer in `onCheckChangedListner()` only

Comment: @Woppi, I was solved my problem with the help of pojo classes if there is any operation that happened on Readio buttons that selected value to be stored in pojo class then you retrieve it later on

Answer (score 0):

Inside your student class add a boolean variable isSelected. Now on checkedChangeListener of each radiogroup, change the value of isSelected to mark whether some value has been selected or no selection has been made. Now inside onBindViewHolder() just do

```
    if(stList.get(position).isSelected){
  viewHolder.rgAnswers.check(stList.get(position).getSelectedRadioButtonId());
    }else{
    viewHolder.rgAnswers.clearCheck();
    }
```

At the end you can iterate over the whole list and check for which objects, isSelected is true

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView came over ListView and its major property that is  **It Reuses cells while scrolling up and down.** 
Due to this it do not flick while scrolling even if you have lots of data in your list.
You are getting problem due to Reuse of cells in RecyclerView.

You can overcome to this problem by binding your RecyclerView list data to Modal class with getter and setter method.
You can display `checkbox` checked or unchecked on basis of cell position and corresponding data.
In my sample i used `setOnClickListener` instead of `setOnCheckedChangeListenerto` to show checkbox checked or unchecked.

Comment: it is working perfect for checkBoxs but we in i implement it for radioButton am getting that issue

Comment: you can use same scenario for radio buttons also.

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problematic piece of code which most of developer does that re register listener again and again.

- So first important point not to register listener in onBindViewHolder
- And second important point to get it resolve by setting tag in efficient way, hence not to save big object in tag so we will only save position.

In my case I am having four radio buttons in a group which lies in a list_item layout:

> ```
> override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
>         val question = questions[position]
>         holder.questionNumberTextView.text = "" + question.id + "."
>         holder.questionTextView.text = question.question
>         holder.myRadioGroup.tag = position
>         if (question.selectedRadioButtonId != -1) {
>             holder.myRadioGroup.check(question.selectedRadioButtonId);
>         } else {
>             //your always need to write else condition
>             holder.myRadioGroup.clearCheck();
>         }
> }
> ```

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    var itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

    val myViewHolder = MyViewHolder(itemLayoutView)
    myViewHolder.myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, radioButtonId ->
        val clickedPos = radioGroup.tag as Int
        Log.i("MyAdapter", "clicked pos:: $clickedPos  radioButtonId :: $radioButtonId")
        questions[clickedPos].selectedRadioButtonId = radioButtonId
    }
    return myViewHolder
}
```

[image]