# Recycler view radio group onCheckedChangeListener is working absurd

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-group

I have created a radio group in recycler view, and implemented onCheckedChangeListener which should work fine.

But for some reasons, after first selection whenever i scroll the recycler view this onCheckedChangeListener gets triggered even though i didn't select any option of radio group.

Here is the code for checked change

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;

        final String id = studentNames.get(position).getStudent_id();
        final String name = studentNames.get(position).getStudent_name();
        holder.id.setText(id);
        holder.name.setText(name);

        holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
                if (radioGroup.isPressed()){ // from one of the links on stackoverflow
                    switch (checkedId) {
                        case R.id.present:
                            calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.present)));
                            break;
                        case R.id.absent:
                            calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.absent)));
                            break;
                        case R.id.leave:
                            calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.leave)));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I added breakpoints in android studio and found out that this onCheckedChange is getting fired even when no option is selected of that radio group.

A related question might have been asked before but they all address Compound Button or CheckBox, I am asking about radio buttons.

PS: I did tried answers from this link [onCheckedChanged called automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641705/oncheckedchanged-called-automatically)

And thats the reason why you see taht radioGroup.isPressed check at the starting

I even used it like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
        RadioButton button= (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
//both getLayoutPosition and getAdapterPosition
        final String id = studentNames.get(getLayoutPosition()).getStudent_id();
        final String name = studentNames.get(getLayoutPosition()).getStudent_name();
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.present:
                if(button.isPressed()){
                    calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(id, name, context.getString(R.string.present)));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.absent:
                if(button.isPressed()) {
                    calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(id , name, context.getString(R.string.absent)));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.leave:
                if(button.isPressed()){
                    calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(id, name, context.getString(R.string.leave)));
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is a very weird problem.

You can always do one thing. Create an integer array of number of items in recycler view and in that array whenever the button is checked, set some value say 1 or 2 or 3. And in onBindViewHolder check if the value of that array for that position is not 0. If 0 then clear radiogroup selection otherwise select that particular group.

For your case you can use this code.

create a global integer array.

```
 private int[] checkedList;
```

inside constructor initialize this array to what your adapter's getItemCount returns i.e. your datamodel size.

```
checkedList = new int[studentNames.size()];
```

now inside onBindViewHolder do the following:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
final MyViewHolder holder = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
        if(checkedList[position] == 1){
            holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.present);
        }else if(checkedList[position] == 2){
            holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.absent);
        }else if(checkedList[position] == 3){
            holder.radioGroup.check(R.id.leave);
        }else{
            holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
        }
    final String id = studentNames.get(position).getStudent_id();
    final String name = studentNames.get(position).getStudent_name();
    holder.id.setText(id);
    holder.name.setText(name);

    holder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
            if (radioGroup.isPressed()){ // from one of the links on stackoverflow
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.present:
                        checkedList[position] = 1;
                        calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.present)));
                        break;
                    case R.id.absent:
                        checkedList[position] = 2;
                        calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.absent)));
                        break;
                    case R.id.leave:
                        checkedList[position] = 3;
                        calculatedAttendance.add(new Attendance(holder.id.getText().toString(), holder.name.getText().toString(), context.getString(R.string.leave)));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```